# SASS syntax (not SCSS) documentation and tools

Tags: css, syntax, sass, scss-mixins

I find SASS syntax much easier and cleaner than SCSS, but the documentation is not as widespread and complete so I often stumble in time wasting syntax errors. Many articles mentioning SASS actually only contain information about SCSS. Even the official SASS documentation (https://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#if) contains examples that apparently only refer to SCSS. For example, what's the SASS syntax for conditional statements in mixins? For example:

```
=button-colors($primary, $secondary, $border: true)
  background-color: $primary
  color: $secondary
if $border
  border-color: $secondary
else
  border-color: $primary
```

This example does not compile correctly: the `if` statement is ignored and there's no `border-color` in the resulting CSS.

Does anybody know about useful websites with documentation and examples of SASS syntax or tools to convert from CSS/SCSS to SASS online?

Comment: If i'm nor wrong, you must compare the value of border, sass doesn't understand **is set**  as true like php or another language you must verify like this

`if $border == true`

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work with `if $border == true` :( I am using this tool to test: https://www.sassmeister.com/

Comment: It's very hard to understand (and quite amazing) why 3 people voted to close this question. Please leave this open, even if you don't care it's not easy to find information online about this

Answer (score 1):

As you saw, The reference document is written in **scss** syntax maybe because of its more popularity and I'm going to highly recommend you choose **scss** syntax because of its most benefits that maybe is not clear at first view!

But anyway if you prefer to use **sass** one, I think you have to follow main document and check [this link](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.INDENTED_SYNTAX.html) to watch the differences and then correct your syntax.

---

You can also use these tools to convert stylesheets:

[css2sass](http://css2sass.herokuapp.com/):  **css** to **scss/sass**.

[sassmeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/):  **scss/sass** to **css**.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the indented syntax documentation (I had not found it before) but it contains very very little information unfortunately